# Add a new e-mail address for the user through the API

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to use PayPal API to add a new e-mail address for the user through the API? Or in general to manage e-mail addresses?

I would like to create a platform which handles payments for the user and would like to register a user-specific platform e-mail for the user so that the platform's e-mail address can be provided to money recipients instead of user's personal e-mail address used for PayPal. (Many recipients tend to send "spammy" e-mails to e-mail adresses they get from PayPal.)